# jq: How to output quotes on raw output on windows

Tags: jq

Using raw output I have to quote some values of the output.

```
echo [{"a" : "b"}] | jq-win64.exe --raw-output ".[] | \"Result is: \" + .a + \".\""
```

generates

```
Result is: b.
```

but how can I generate

```
Result is: "b".
```

Unfortunately it has to run on Windows called from inside a CMD file.

Comment: What happens when you try `\"Result is: \"\"\" + .a + \"\"\".\"`

Comment: jq: error: syntax error, unexpected QQSTRING_START, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1: .[] | "Result is: """ + .a + """."
jq: 1 compile error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the slashes to escape a `"`

```
$ echo [{"a" : "b"}] | jq-win64.exe --raw-output ".[] | \"Result is: \\\"\" + .a + \"\\\".\""
Result is: "b".
```

Answer (score 2):

A hacky workaround with less backslashing could be:

```
jq -r ".[] | \"Result is: \" + (.a|tojson)"
```

[REVISED to reflect OP goal.]

Comment: Oh right, that would definitely work, but he'll only want the json representation of the `a` property, not the entire object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to output double quotes in a double quoted string, you need to escape the inner quotes.  And to escape the inner quotes, you need to also escape the escaping backslashes.  So a literal double quote would have to be entered as `\\\"`.  You can do this a little cleaner by using string interpolation instead of regular string concatenation.

```
jq -r ".[] | \"Result is: \\\"\(.a)\\\".\""
```